# Concise nil checks for struct field pointers?

Tags: pointers, go, struct, null, comparison

Say I have this struct:

```
type Foo struct {
    Bar        *string          `json:"bar"`
    Baz        *int64           `json:"baz,omitempty"`
    Qux        *string          `json:"qux"`
    Quux       string           `json:"quux"`
}
```

After unmarshalling the json, I check for nil like so:

```
switch {
case f.Bar == nil:
    return errors.New("Missing 'bar'")
case f.Baz == nil:
    f.Baz = 42
case f.Qux == nil:
    return errors.New("Missing 'qux'")
}
```

(or through a series of `if` statements, etc...)

I understand that I can put all the `nil` comparisons in one comma separated `case`, but each `nil` check will have differing returns.

My question: is there a less verbose way of doing the nil checks?

Comment: Hey rebel... in your switch statement, you seem to be looking at two different values of `Foo` **f** and **m**, is that intentional or are you just looking for a general idiom for validation?

Comment: that's a typo - thanks for catching that! I'm just looking for a general idiom for validation.

Comment: Can you elaborate on 'each nil check will have differing returns.' ? Are you setting default values ?

Comment: I updated the switch statement. Thanks for taking a look.

Comment: does JSON schema help? https://github.com/xeipuuv/gojsonschema

Comment: @rebelshrug - These links should help you out. [Link1](http://brandonokert.com/2016/04/18/Json-Management-Patterns-In-Go/) & [Link2](https://godoc.org/gopkg.in/validator.v2#hdr-Builtin_validator_functions)

Comment: @JiangYD - JSON schema looks good, but I prefer to write it myself.

Comment: @JohnSPerayil - thanks for the links, they were very helpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A question to you: how less verbose you want to get? Because you want to do different things on different conditions (different fields being `nil`). Your code contains these different things and the different conditions. Beyond that what's "redundant" in your code are just the `switch` and `case` keywords. You want to leave them out? Because the rest is not "redundant", they are required.

Also note that in Go `case`s do not fall through even without a `break` (unlike in other languages), so in your above example if `f.Baz` is `nil`, you will set it to `42` and `f.Qux` will not be checked (so no `error` will be returned), but if `f.Baz` is non-`nil` and `f.Qux` is `nil`, an `error` will be returned. I know it's just an example, but this is something to keep in mind. You should handle `error`s first if you use a `switch`! Or use `if` statements and then the error will be detected and returned regardless of the order of field checks.

Your code with `switch` is clean and efficient. If you want to make it less verbose, readability (and performance) will suffer.

You may use a helper function which checks if a pointer value is `nil`:

```
func n(i interface{}) bool {
    v := reflect.ValueOf(i)
    return v.Kind() == reflect.Ptr && v.IsNil()
}
```

And using it:

```
func check(f *Foo) error {
    switch {
    case n(f.Bar):
        return errors.New("Missing 'bar'")
    case n(f.Qux):
        return errors.New("Missing 'qux'")
    case n(f.Baz):
        x := int64(42)
        f.Baz = &x
    }
    return nil
}
```

Or using `if` statements:

```
func check2(f *Foo) error {
    if n(f.Bar) {
        return errors.New("Missing 'bar'")
    }
    if n(f.Qux) {
        return errors.New("Missing 'qux'")
    }
    if n(f.Baz) {
        x := int64(42)
        f.Baz = &x
    }
    return nil
}
```

Try these on the [Go Playground](https://play.golang.org/p/_pYbMyKz8I).

Comment: Thanks for the help - the tip about Go `case`s saved me some heartache. I did go with the helper function route.